# Python Opencv OBJECT TRACKING. Measure distance between tho points from first frame (camera or video feed) and store it for later use

Tags: python, opencv, object, distance, tracking

I have a project in which I have to measure the distance between two moving points in real-time and to calculate how much every point travelled (in mm or pixels) from the initial position. I have managed so far to get every value (x, y coordinates) from every frame, but I need the coordinates of the points from the first frame. I need to calculate in real-time what is the distance that every point travelled at any time.
The points will be placing more or less in the same position in the real world but I need to read the initial distance between them using OpenCV and python from the camera feed. 
This is a fragment of the code from where I have managed to take the x, y value for each point for each frame.
I have attached am image with the schematics. I need to STORE the x, y for both points at FRAME 1 something like:

point_1_x_value_Frame_1 = some value and store or remain constant

point_1_y_value_Frame_1 = some value and store or remain constant

point_2_x_value_Frame_1 = some value and store or remain constant

point_2_y_value_Frame_1 = some value and store or remain constant

Thank you

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()

width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_number = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
frame_count = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

next, status, error = cv.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_gray, gray, prev, None, **lk_params)       
good_old = prev[status == 1]
good_new = next[status == 1]

for i, (new, old) in enumerate(zip(good_new, good_old)):
    a, b = new.ravel()
    c, d = old.ravel()
    mask = cv.line(mask, (a, b), (c, d), color, 2)
    frame = cv.circle(frame, (a, b), 1, (255, 0, 0), 3)

    if a < width/2:
        PCT_1_xn = a # x coord for point 1
        PCT_1_yn = b # y coord for point 1
    elif a > width/2:
        PCT_2_xn = a # x coord for point 2
        PCT_2_yn = b # y coord for point 2
```

Schematic representation:
[image]

Comment: did you manage to get any solution for this yet?

Comment: Yes! The project is well ahead by this time! One of the solutions is to store the data in *.txt files with timestamp and use what I need from there. The initial plan was modified so that I needed values from specific time-frames.